# (Three.js) how can i get indices from STL file after load stl file with loader?

Tags: three.js

i have a question,
i want to get vertices and indices from stl file from STLLoader of Three.js.
i can get vertices but, i can't get indices...

i tried

```
console.log(STLgeometry)
```

but the index attribute is null....

is there any chance to get indices..?

and i tried for loop

```
//arr = devided vertices array in 3 elements
// ex) arr =[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2]...,] 
//but there are same elements ex) [[x1,y1,z1],..,[x1,y1,z1]]
// so i remove same elements and that called "node" array

//if node's element and arr's elment is same, take that index and push it to "indices" array.
//but it takes so much time..... if vertices array is too big.
  
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < node.length; j++) {
      if (String(arr[i]) === String(node[j])) {
        indices.push(j);
      }
    }
  }
```

i really need your help.

Comment: There are no indices inside [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) but you can hardcode indices as each consequent 3 vertexes represent triangle ... so you just encode your indices like this `indices[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...}` or multiples of per vertex data size (depends on your representation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STL has no concept of vertex indices. Meaning the triangles in an STL file do not share vertices. Hence, `THREE.STLLoader` returns an non-indexed geometry.

Try to use the utility function [BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices). It will return a new indexed geometry by merging equal vertex data.

Comment: yes there are no indices in STL however one of he fundamental properties of STL is that triangles share all Vertexes exactly twice (however in the file they are duplicated) ... and not just Vertexes but edges too ...